# how to align 4 DIV's right of each other within another DIV

Tags: css

i want to position 4 divs next to each other, at a certain position within the parent div.
So the div structure is this (i'll call the top most div the maindiv):

```
<div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
</div>
```

now i want to set div with text '1' at the left in the maindiv

now i want to set div with text '2' at 50 px from the left side in the maindiv

now i want to set div with text '3' at 150 px from the left side in the maindiv

now i want to set div with text '4' at 200 px from the left side in the maindiv

I think :-) i have tried ALL possible css constructs, but it didn't work, sadly.

Anyone an idea?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Give `position: relative` to the main div

`position: absolute` to the children and position them using `left: xyz; top: xyz` .

Comment: please, please... tell me why this works (because it does!)
it is in the 'relative', because when i delete that, the inner divs are placed at the top of the page. I've mad a pge with a table an d underneath this div with the innerdivs, and it's all fine. I can copy paste the div/innerdivs and they appear correct too. But when i delete the 'position:relative', the innerd vis (not the outer!!) are placed at the top of my page (Ie8 and FF3). That, dear sir, can not be figured out by me :). Can you explain why this behaviour exists? to be clear: the answer is correct, just want to understand why.

Comment: @Michel absolutely positioned elements are always positioned relatively to the *next parent element* with either `position: relative` or `position: absolute` (and I think, also `position: fixed`). Basic theory here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#absolute-positioning if the parent div is not `position: relative`, the absolute positioning is relative to the topmost element, the body. Thus, `left: 50px` will then actually mean 50 pixels from the document's left hand corner.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this would help you

```
                <div> 
                    <div style="float: left;">1</div> 
                    <div style="float: left; margin-left: 50px;">2</div> 
                    <div style="float: left; margin-left: 100px;">3</div> 
                    <div style="float: left;margin-left: 50px;">4</div> 
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 div div
      {
          float:left;
          margin-left:50px;
      }
```

EDIT:as in: Fix for the parent:

```
div
{
    float:left;
    margin-left:-50px;
}
div div
{
    float:left;
    margin-left:50px;
}
```

Comment: NOTE: this moves the first div child also, so you could put a -50px margin on the parent if that is an issue.

Answer (score 0):

## flexbox

Flexbox is now the recommended way, simply because it's the most simple and easiest solution

```css
.parent{
  display:inline-flex;
}
.child{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```